# How to make a ggplot2 plot inside of an R function using a column name (string) as input?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a histogram inside a function like this:

```
norm.plot <- function(col_name, bw) {
  temp_df = pitchbook[!is.na(pitchbook[col_name]), c(col_name)]
  ggplot(temp_df, aes_string(x=col_name))  + 
  geom_histogram(color="blue", fill="cyan", binwidth = bw) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 
    dnorm(x, mean = mean(temp_df[col_name]), sd = sd(temp_df[col_name])) * nrow(temp_df) * bw)
}
```

But I get an error

```
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
Computation failed in `stat_function()`: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How do I properly input the column name to avoid this error?

Comment: Have a look at the [ggplot2 vignette](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function-1)

Comment: by the way - this is the first result when I googled your *exact* question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help but not tested in lack of data:

```
#Code
norm.plot <- function(col_name, bw) {
  temp_df = pitchbook[!is.na(pitchbook[col_name]), c(col_name)]
  ggplot(temp_df, aes_string(x=col_name))  + 
  geom_histogram(color="blue", fill="cyan", binwidth = bw)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `aes_string` fixed my first issue, but it still yields to problems as I add more to my `ggplot` command. Can you please take a look at my edit above?

Comment: @shurup It is better if you compute the mean and sd outside the stat and then pass the values to it like `v1 <- mean(temp_df[col_name])` and then pass `v1` to the stat.